# Any other method to solve "automation error"

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to successfully complete (with so much help from a stack exchange user) a macro to automatically mail merge a word document from excel. But the problem now is, unless the word document is open, I get an automation error.

Right now, I solve it by just opening the word document every time, but I doubt that is the right programming method.

Any suggestions to overcome this error? I am very new to VBA. This is part of my student assignments.  Any advise or code changes to help overcome this error? I read the official msdn docs, did not understand a thing. :'(

The error is usually "automation error - with a cross sign" or this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDJS3.jpg
For both these errors, solution so far was to open the word document first and then run macro.

Update:
I removed "on error..." part and now the error is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v75qd.jpg

The program is as follows:

```
Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

Sub RunMerge2()
Dim wd As Object, wdocSource As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim cdir As String, client As String, newname As String
    Dim sSQL As String

    cdir = "C:\Users\Kamlesh\Desktop\"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(cdir & "\master\installers.docx")
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    With sh
        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lrow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                client = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                newname = "Installer Instructions - " & client & ".docx"

                wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

                '~~> Sample String
                sSQL = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$` WHERE [Client Name] = '" & .Range("A" & i).Value & "'"

                wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
                SQLStatement:=sSQL

                With wdocSource.MailMerge
                    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                    .SuppressBlankLines = True
                    With .DataSource
                        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
                    End With
                    .Execute Pause:=False
                End With

                wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs cdir & newname
                wd.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'wd.Quit

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: check my update on how to find where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(cdir & "\master\installers.docx")
```

should be

```
Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(cdir & "master\installers.docx")
```

and

```
strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
```

can be replaced with

```
strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

---

To find what part of the code is causing the error, in Tools > Options > Editor tab check everything

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/09/85/90/71/VBA%20Options.gif))</sub>

and in the General tab check everything and select `Break in Class Module`

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC314067.jpg))</sub>
.aspx#odc_ac2007_ta_ErrorHandlingAndDebuggingTipsForAccessVBAndVBA_BasicErrorHandling)

Comment: The existing code (the part you want replaced) is necessary to handle the case where Word is already running. (And answers don't suggest *try*ing  something. A suggestion should be posted as a comment to the question.

Comment: anyway, i removed that part and posted screenshot. Hope this helps to debug the problem.

Comment: @Ken White that's exactly why I suggested it in case the problem was with the already running Word instance.

Comment: As I said, a **suggestion** belongs in a comment to the original question. A *suggestion* is  not an *answer*.

Comment: @kenwhite the question is "Any other method to solve “automation error”" so I think even a suggestion is an answer to that question :] and fitting that in a comment would be pretty challenging.

Comment: The place where the error happens is: 

   wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
                SQLStatement:=sSQL